# Partial sums of a dictionary's values

Tags: python

Given a dictionary, I need to calculate the sum of the logarithms of the values contained in the dictionary, until that sum is greater than 1.

I've started by calculating the partial sums:

```
r = [itertools.accumulate(math.log(items.values(),2))]
```

But I'm stuck on how to terminate the operation when the sum gets greater than 1.

Comment: Please note that python dictionaries are not meant to store the order of the inserted key-value pairs (e.g. you shouldn't use a dictionary to iterate a dictionary until some condition is true). So either use an ordered collection such as a list or switch to an ordered-dictionary implementations, such as this one : http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/raw-file/tip/odict.py

Comment: did you have a look at `itertools.takewhile()` ?

Comment: @yonili: the OP is using Python 3 (see the `itertools.accumulate`), so `OrderedDict` is available from the `collections` module.

Comment: @JohannesP I didn't know that even existed! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
takewhile(lambda x: x<1, accumulate(math.log(x,2) for x in items.values()))
```

Comment: ... except that `math.log` cannot actually be applied to a `dict_values`.

Comment: Ok, I'll sort that out.

Comment: I just keep on getting <itertools.takewhile object at 0x02C39300> as the output

Comment: @TomKealy Wrap the whole thing in `list(...)`.

Comment: @arshajii Thanks! Am new to python.